# Binary operation on sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, logic, binary-operations

> Assume there exists at least a set (namely the empty set: $\emptyset$) and assume also that you have defined just one binary operation $P$ on any collection of sets (including those formed through the operation itself):
> $$ P(A, B) = \begin{cases} \{A, B\} & \text{if } A \neq B \\ \{A\} & \text{if } A=B  \end{cases}
> $$
> where $\{A, B\}$ denotes an unordered pair and $\{A\}$ denotes a singleton.

Now, my questions are:

- How many sets can I construct using only the operation $P$?

It is clear that the answer is infinitely many, however then it remains to clarify if it's a countable or uncountable infinity we are talking about;

- Is there the possibility that applying P in different ways could yield the same sets?

I do not even know how to start answering this one.

As always, any hint or comment is highly appreciated and let me know if I can explain my self clearer!

Comment: For the first question, let $S_0=\emptyset$ and $S_n=P(S_{n-1},\emptyset)$. What can you say about the sequence $S_n$?

Comment: @Taladris Is it a sequence of countably many infinite sets?

Comment: Here is your hint: induction is how you approach it. Define $\emptyset$ as generation $0$, and build each generation from the sets in the previous generation.  The final answers are countably infinite, and no, other than $P(A,B) = P(B,A)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is a great answer! In the end I managed to find an answer to the second question myself however the idea of “generations” is amazing!

Comment: I borrowed it from Conway and Knuth's definition of the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number). Since their scheme is more powerful than yours, they were not limited to a countably infinite collection. (The two arguments of their equivalent of $P$ are sets of surreals, not individual surreals,)